# Can't create a new object in Springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot web application. I have a another project, a jar file. I added this jar file to web application and created a new object from the jar file. There is no compilation error. but when ever I run I am getting run time exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. I don't know what's going wrong. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: How did you add the jar to your application?

Comment: It means compiler looking for a class which is not available in the class path!. So tell me for which class you are creating the object and look closely into stack trace for which class the compiler expecting at run time

Comment: @WilcoGreven I have used <dependency> tag and allso installed the jar in my local maven repository

Comment: Can you be more descriptive with the architecture you're using and provide some more information with a better stacktrace.

Comment: After packing the jar file unpack it and check whether the class is available in jar file

Comment: @RajeshHatwar The class is available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Maven, you're probably missing the [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Without this you'll just get a small JAR with just your classes. With this plugin you get a "full" jar which contains all the dependencies you need.